# how to create only time picker in angular 5 or 6?

Tags: angular, timepicker

I have to select specific time from given time slot. after selecting the date from the calendar available time slot will be shown for appointment.

Comment: You meant plugin?

Comment: @SangwinGawande i can use plugin from primeng . Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

There is one in [Bootstrap DateTime Picker](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

Which has exact component you need.

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datetimepicker"
    data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="hh">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Invoke it like : `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('remove')`

### [image: Bootstrap Datetime Picker]

You can use [PrimeNG Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar).

```
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';
```

It has `timeOnly` parameter which only shows time picker.

[image: TimePicker]

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date8" [timeOnly]="true"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: I did this but i have to show the time just like table or grid. I can't select time using input box i have to select it from the available slot it displaying

Comment: Is it work for inline="true" for timepicker ? @Sangwin

Comment: Can you show me an example like how do you need it?

Comment: https://d585tldpucybw.cloudfront.net/sfimages/default-source/productsimages/winforms/controls/screenshots/winforms_timepicker_dropdown.png?sfvrsn=4a9db4bd_3

Comment: This will work for you then `(Check Hour view)` : https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1):

[Time Picker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples)

```
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time"></ngb-timepicker>
```

Comment: Your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).